# How to get values of dynamically generated labels of multiple checkboxes in Angular 4?

Tags: html, angular, forms, checkbox, angular4-forms

I need to get the values of labels for check boxes if the checkbox is selected.

How can I pass label values on checked?

```
<div *ngFor="let list1 of list['data']">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let CheckBoxOptions of list1['sample']">
        <label 
          [for]="CheckBoxOptions?.value" 
          class="col-sm-4">
          {{CheckBoxOptions?.value}}
        </label>
        <input 
          class="col-sm-8 form-control" 
          [type]="checkbox" 
          [(ngModel)]="CheckBoxOptions.Checked" 
          [checked]="CheckBoxOptions.Checked" 
          (change)="CheckBoxOptions.Checked = !CheckBoxOptions.Checked" 
          value="{{CheckBoxOptions.value}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code where you're creating the checkboxes

Comment: Code would be beneficial for us to debug the error/suggestions

Comment: added please check

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could pass the `CheckBoxOptions` to the `(change)` event. Then you can handle it in the TypeScript class based on the `[(ngModel)]` value.

```
<div *ngFor="let list1 of list['data']">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let CheckBoxOptions of list1['sample']">
        <label 
          [for]="CheckBoxOptions?.value" 
          class="col-sm-4">
          {{CheckBoxOptions?.value}}
        </label>
        <input 
          class="col-sm-8 form-control" 
          type="checkbox" 
          [(ngModel)]="CheckBoxOptions.Checked" 
          [checked]="CheckBoxOptions.Checked" 
          (change)="changed(CheckBoxOptions)" 
          [value]="CheckBoxOptions.value">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in your TypeScript class,

```
changed(CheckBoxOptions) {
  console.log(CheckBoxOptions);
}
```

If your `CheckBoxOptions.checked` is `true` there, you can use the `value` of `CheckBoxOptions`

Also, there was some property binding syntax that I've removed.

Here's a **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-storage-eg)** to help you out. Just have a look at the Upper List and check the console for the values of item.

Comment: Working. But not selected values are undefined.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not selected values here?

Comment: probably the values bound to the checkboxes on which you haven't clicked yet.

Comment: But why would `changed` be called for those when they haven't changed in the first place? I've also fixed some property binding syntax that wasn't really required.

Comment: yes, I don't think this is a problem either. Also for all practical purposes, undefined is a falsy value.